# PostGIS Tiger Geocoder can't get any result

Tags: postgresql, debugging, geocoding, postgis

I followed the doc to install postgresql postgis. I also loaded many states data into database. It all looks normal and I didn't get any error during the loading process. But when I ran the query to geocode an address, it doesn't return any result (my database cover that state already!)

So I'm wondering if there's a way to debug, I've looked up online for two days but all there have is tutorial or documentation on loading no debugging. This should be a common issue for many developer.

Comment: What sort of query are you trying to debug?